# How do I remove an unpushed commit caused by a large file in the repo that has since been deleted?

Tags: git, git-commit

I am fairly beginner in git. My repo has simple MATLAB code files. I made the mistake of uploading a large file into the repo (> 100 MB).  After that, I used the following commands

```
git add --all
git commit --all --message "Moar"
git push --all
```

The push command threw up the following error :

> remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git
>   Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
>       remote: error: Trace: 47cf7a12aa48e59e3007901d70e3843b
>       remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
>       remote: error: File prepro/workbench-windows64-v1.3.2/workbench/bin_windows64/rfMRI_REST1_LR_Atlas.dtseries.nii
>   is 418.46 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
>          ...
>           ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

I then panicked and deleted the above large file that was causing the error. But now I still get the same errors when I try to push to my master!!

These large files do not exist in my local repo anymore. So why isn't git letting me push ?  Also, I have some changes in the local repo after this happened so I cannot revert back to the most recent commit without these large files.

Is there a way to cleanly and precisely do it by letting git know that the large files do not exist in the repo anymore?

Comment: The large files *are still in your repository*. Your repository contains the commits; and each commit contains every file that was committed. You added a later commit that *doesn't* have the file, but the earlier one still does. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a beginner, read this answer it will supply a lot of information to you.
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head) & Undo commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head-undo-commits/34519716#34519716)

---

In order to remove content from old commit, im recommending this tool:

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

It the perfect tool for this kind of task

> #### BFG Repo-Cleaner
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> - Removing Crazy Big Files
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```